# Finding a Degree Function: Let $R=\Bbb Z[i]$ and let $d(x)=N(x)$ for $x∈R$, where $N(x)$ is the norm of $x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> (a) For $x,y∈R$−{0},show that $d(x)≤d(xy)$
>
> (b) Let $x=2+10i$ and $y=5+3i$. Find $q,r∈R$ such that $x=yq+r$ where either $r=0$ or $d(r) < d(y)$

For the first part of the question I don't know how I would prove this but it seems obvious that $x≤xy$ so I am not sure logically how I would say this.

For the second question I have so far $5+3i/2+10i$=$(5+3i)(2-10i)/(2+10i)(2-10i)$=$40-44i/104$ but I don't know how I would proceed after that to show what it is asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(a)$, use the fact that $d$ is a multiplicative function: $d(xy)=d(x)d(y)$.

For $(b)$, you can write $$2+10i = (a+bi)(5+3i) + (c+di).$$

Simplify to get $$2+10i = 5a - 3b + c + (3a+5b+d)i.$$

Now see if you can spot a solution $(a, b)$ such that $c^2 + d^2 < 5^2 + 3^2 = 34$.

Comment: For part a, can we just cancel out the d(x) then and see 1<d(y) since 1 exist in R then it proves it?  For the second part I have only done these type of questions where you can graph it so finding a,b,c,d were not difficult so I have no idea how you would find (a,b) using the last thing you wrote...

Comment: @user710744 Yeah, you can cancel $d(x)$ and show that for all $y \in R$, $y \ \neq 0$, we have $d(y) \geq 1$. For the second part, you should just plug in some numbers to minimize, say, $c$ first. $(a, b) = (1, 1)$ forces $c=0$ and $d=2$ so that works: $q= 1+i$, $r=2i$.